# Different conditional lock in 2 functions

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have 2 function used in multi-threaded environment.

```
static std::vector<MyType> shared_resource;
void funcA(){
    // remove/add object to shared_resource
}

void funcB(){
    // Use shared_resource (but never changes it)
}
```

I have to synchronise 2 functions so that while funcA is operating on the shared resource, funcB waits it. One obvious solution is use critical section but if I use it function call to funcB is also serialised and that is what I do not want.
 I mean that I want to permit multiple threads to execute funcB at the same time but once funcA is called from another thread all the threads going into funcB being blocked and after all the thread executing funcB exit, the thread at the funcA is resumed and execute it.

I do not know if my explanation is clear so I write an example. Assume that we have thread T1 to T5. And this is expected behaviour.

1. T1 and T2 entered into funcB and executing funcB at the same time.
2. T3 is entering funcA and wait T1 and T2 exit from funcB
3. T4 is entering funcB but since T3 is waiting for executing funcA, T4 is blocked executing funcB
4. After T1 and T2 exits T3 executes funcA
5. T5 is entering funcB but since funcA is still being executed it is blocked
6. After T3 exits from funcA, T4 and T5 executes funcB at the same time.

What should I use to achieve this behaviour? Semaphore? I'm implementing it in Windows/C++ environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the so called readers-writer lock, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). You can find a a simple implementation using pthreads  [here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/PLN/RWLock.c).

Comment: Thanks this is what I want to know!